# how to hide a couple of fields on custom object for a certain profile in one shot

Tags: administration

We have a custom object and I would like to hide some fields on it for a certain profile in one shot. I know how to go individually on field level security but I don't want to go that route because the list of fields is long and it will take for ever. I also don't want to assign different page layouts to different profiles because we already have a lot of page layouts.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some additional context that hasn't been shared, this should be as simple as navigating to the profile-centric security view:

Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Profiles > [click the profile name] > Object Settings > [click the appropriate object] > [click Edit] > change & save

Comment: I don't need to hide the whole object or restrict permissions. I have hundreds of fields on our custom object and on about 50 fields I needed to hide it from a certain profile. I know how to do field level security but that is too time consuming.

Comment: @user2363530, If this solution does not work for you, I would suggest editing your question and providing more details so that the community can assist. As it's written, it is unclear what your desired solution might entail.